# DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'Driver_Name'

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

```
 string[] Parameters = new string[3] { "@USER_ID", "@Company_ID", "@DRIVER_NAME" };
    string[] DbTypes = new string[3] { "varchar", "int", "varchar" };
    string[] ParameterTypes = new string[3] { "input", "input", "input" };
    string[] values = new string[3] { (Session["UserID"].ToString()), ddlCompany.SelectedValue.ToString(), txt_DRIVER_NAME.Text.Trim() };
    string[] Lengths = new string[3] { "50", "5", "20" };

    DataUtility du = new DataUtility();
    DataSet ds = du.returnDataSet(CommandType.StoredProcedure, "Driver_Zone_Wise", Parameters, DbTypes, ParameterTypes, values, Lengths);

    lb_DriverList.DataTextField = "Driver_Name";
    lb_DriverList.DataValueField = "DRIVER_ID";

    lb_DriverList.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    ****lb_DriverList.DataBind();****

    lb_DriverList.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Vehicle", "0"));

    lb_DriverList.SelectedValue = "0";

}
```

Answer (score 3):

The error suggesting that you don't have `Driver_Name` in your query result.

Check your query and `ds.Tables[0]` and see weather you have the column `Driver_Name` or not.

### Edit -1

Check you procedure `Driver_Zone_Wise` are make sure you are returning the column with name `Driver_Name`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have `Driver_Name` field in your resultant dataset you bound to `lb_DriverList`.

Check the result set of `ds`

Answer (score 1):

The error is self explanatory. It seems your result is not having `DRIVER_NAME` in it. Or your Database is not having such column check your database.

I will advice you to insert breakpoint at the result where you are filling your dataset and then debug it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

your code error ddlCompany.SelectedValue.ToString() 
you changed

```
string[] values = new string[3] { (Session["UserID"].ToString()), int.Parse(ddlCompany.SelectedValue.ToString()), txt_DRIVER_NAME.Text.Trim() };
```